# <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)>

Tags: python-3.6

```
import pandas as pd
A = pd.read_html('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vfNVRdRn-e00XpDB8L7wUJEqFiLHTfAL5yUhNBS0KEk')
B = pd.read_csv(A)
new_df = df[['col1', 'col2']]  # Выберем из датафрейма 2 столбца и сохраним в новый датафрейм
new_df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False) # Экспорт в CSV файл
```

Comment: 1. [A URL, a file-like object, or a raw string containing HTML. Note that lxml only accepts the http, ftp and file url protocols. If you have a URL that starts with 'https' you might try removing the 's'.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html#pandas-read-html) 2. с чего бы должен загружаться документ с ограниченными правами доступа?

Comment: все равно не реботает